# Plot of Density, type="l"

Tags: r, plot, density-plot

I have a output for density estimation.

```
$x
 [1] 0.100001 0.600001 0.500001 0.800001 0.500001 0.100001 0.600001 0.300001
 [9] 0.100001 0.400001 0.700001 0.500001 0.000001 0.200001 0.700001 0.500001
[17] 0.000001 0.400001 0.500001 0.400001 0.200001 0.100001 0.600001 0.700001
[25] 0.700001 0.200001 0.800001 0.500001 0.200001 0.200001

$y
 [1] 1.2246774 1.1437131 1.3626914 0.6381394 1.3626914 1.2246774 1.1437131
 [8] 1.5893983 1.2246774 1.5158009 0.8852983 1.3626914 0.6912818 1.5227328
[15] 0.8852983 1.3626914 0.6912818 1.5158009 1.3626914 1.5158009 1.5227328
[22] 1.2246774 1.1437131 0.8852983 0.8852983 1.5227328 0.6381394 1.3626914
[29] 1.5227328 1.5227328
```

where `x` are grid points and `y` are estimated values. When these are plotted, its graph is very weird with type `"l"`
[image: as given below:]. Its a density plot which should have a single line. Please guide me how it can be soughed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to plot them in the correct order (ordered according to the value of x):

```r
 plot(sort(x), y[order(x)], type = "l")
```

[image]

---

**Reproducible data**

```r
x <- c(0.100001, 0.600001, 0.500001, 0.800001, 0.500001, 0.100001, 
       0.600001, 0.300001, 0.100001, 0.400001, 0.700001, 0.500001, 1e-06, 
       0.200001, 0.700001, 0.500001, 1e-06, 0.400001, 0.500001, 0.400001, 
       0.200001, 0.100001, 0.600001, 0.700001, 0.700001, 0.200001, 0.800001, 
       0.500001, 0.200001, 0.200001)

y <- c(1.2246774, 1.1437131, 1.3626914, 0.6381394, 1.3626914, 1.2246774, 
       1.1437131, 1.5893983, 1.2246774, 1.5158009, 0.8852983, 1.3626914, 
       0.6912818, 1.5227328, 0.8852983, 1.3626914, 0.6912818, 1.5158009, 
       1.3626914, 1.5158009, 1.5227328, 1.2246774, 1.1437131, 0.8852983, 
       0.8852983, 1.5227328, 0.6381394, 1.3626914, 1.5227328, 1.5227328)
```

Note that in your data, for some reason there are multiple points with the same values.